# Jquery Ajax: Cannot assign to a function result error

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my ajax servlet I am setting a list of objects to request attribute.

```
 request.setAttribute("testModelList",testList);
```

In my script I am trying to retrieve the attribute and set in to hidden variable.

```
// my JS 
$('#testDetails').val() = '${testModelList}';
```

My jsp

```
<INPUT type="hidden" id = "testDetails" >
```

But I am getting an error

> Cannot assign to a function result

Can anyone help me how to get the request attribute list to the hidden variable in JSP through Ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assign a value to the *result* of a function:

```
$('#testDetails').val() = '${testModelList}';
```

But you *can* pass the value *to* the function:

```
$('#testDetails').val('${testModelList}');
```

Comment: Thanks @David. it resolved the error. But I could not retrieve the value from the hidden variable in another request from the same page. Any idea?..See my code below
"request.getParameter("errorDetails"); //I am getting null"

Comment: @Hari: There's no code in your question related to this new issue you're describing.  I recommend you open a new Stack Overflow question and provide details about that separate problem.